# I can't build my NextJS project on Vercel

Tags: next.js, build, jsx, vercel

I'm doing my first landing page with NextJS and Vercel, I finished the mobile version and I would like to deploy the project to see what looks like. When I try to build the repository on Vercel, I get this error every time:

**Type error: Page "src/app/page.jsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
"Container" is not a valid Page export field.**

My repository: https://github.com/lucasandradegs/desafio-prominas

*locale, using npm run dev it's normal.

PLEASE, HELP ME

I don't have any ideia what it could be, I don't know what to try.